# store hex value (0x45E213) in an integer

Tags: java, android, hex, numberformatexception

In my application I used a converter to create from 3 values > RGB-colors an Hex value.
I use this to set my gradient background in my application during runtime.

Now is this the following problem.
The result of the converter is a `(String)` `#45E213`, and this can't be stored in an integer.
But when you create an integer,

```
int hex = 0x45E213;
```

it does work properly, and this doesn't give errors.

Now I knew of this, I Replaced the `#` to `0x`, and tried it to convert from String to Integer.

```
int hexToInt = new Integer("0x45E213").intValue();
```

But now I get the `numberFormatException`, because while converting, it will not agree with the character `E`?

How can I solve this? Because I really need it as an Integer or Java/Eclipse won't use it in its method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

The Integer constructor with a string behaves the same as parseInt with radix 10. You presumably want String.parseInt with radix 16.

```
Integer.parseInt("45E213", 16)
```

or to cut off the 0x

```
Integer.parseInt("0x45E213".substring(2), 16);
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt("0x45E213".replace("0x",""), 16);
```

Comment: I guess you mean Integer.parseInt("45E213");. You would need to strip 0x from the String

Comment: Thanks for the ParseInt idea, and the fast reply, it worked. only my background isn't changing color, but that would be an other fix.

Comment: You have and extra closing parenthesis in both Integer.parseInt functions.

Answer (score 7):

The lesser known Integer.decode(String) might be useful here. Note it will also do leading zeros as octal, which you might not want, but if you're after something cheap and cheerful...

```
int withHash = Integer.decode("#45E213");
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(withHash));

int withZeroX = Integer.decode("0x45E213");
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(withZeroX));
```

Output

```
45e213
45e213
```

Answer (score 4):

This Method accepts your String
you can use `Color.parseColor(String)` but you need to replace `0x` prefix with `#`

Comment: This would be helpfull if i need Colors to set the background, and this is when i just need 1 solid color, but i need to create a gradient background, and therefor you need two heximals.